# OpenCL clCreateCommandQueue CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY error

Tags: gpu, opencl, ubuntu-16.04, amd-gpu

I'm trying to use an OpenCL sample HelloWorld to see if everything is working properly. I have no problem of compilation, however, I have a CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY at the clCreateCommandQueue().

Here what I get

```
[thomas@thomas-OptiPlex-9020:/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64]$ ./HelloWorld
input string:
GdkknVnqkc

output string:
�����
Passed!
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with Oland AMD Radeon HD 8600 Series . I have install the latest AMDGPU-PRO driver available [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) as well as the AMD APP SDK 3.0 for 64-bit Linux [here](http://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/). The clinfo output is presented in below.

```
[thomas@thomas-OptiPlex-9020:~]$ clinfo
Number of platforms:                 1
Platform Profile:                FULL_PROFILE
Platform Version:                OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2348.3)
Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform Vendor:                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform Extensions:                 cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


Platform Name:               AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               2
Device Type:                     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
Vendor ID:                   1002h
Board name:                  AMD Radeon HD 8600 Series
Device Topology:                 PCI[ B#1, D#0, F#0 ]
Max compute units:               6
Max work items dimensions:           3
Max work items[0]:               256
Max work items[1]:               256
Max work items[2]:               256
Max work group size:                 256
Preferred vector width char:             4
Preferred vector width short:            2
Preferred vector width int:          1
Preferred vector width long:             1
Preferred vector width float:            1
Preferred vector width double:       1
Native vector width char:            4
Native vector width short:           2
Native vector width int:             1
Native vector width long:            1
Native vector width float:           1
Native vector width double:          1
Max clock frequency:                 1050Mhz
Address bits:                    32
Max memory allocation:           1391308800
Image support:               Yes
Max number of images read arguments:         128
Max number of images write arguments:        8
Max image 2D width:              16384
Max image 2D height:                 16384
Max image 3D width:              2048
Max image 3D height:                 2048
Max image 3D depth:              2048
Max samplers within kernel:          16
Max size of kernel argument:             1024
Alignment (bits) of base address:        2048
Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:  128
Single precision floating point capability
Denorms:                     No
Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
Round to nearest even:           Yes
Round to zero:               Yes
Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
Cache type:                  Read/Write
Cache line size:                 64
Cache size:                  16384
Global memory size:              2107346944
Constant buffer size:                65536
Max number of constant args:             8
Local memory type:               Scratchpad
Local memory size:               32768
Max pipe arguments:              0
Max pipe active reservations:            0
Max pipe packet size:                0
Max global variable size:            0
Max global variable preferred total size:    0
Max read/write image args:           0
Max on device events:                0
Queue on device max size:            0
Max on device queues:                0
Queue on device preferred size:      0
SVM capabilities:                
  Coarse grain buffer:           No
  Fine grain buffer:                 No
  Fine grain system:                 No
  Atomics:                   No
Preferred platform atomic alignment:         0
Preferred global atomic alignment:       0
Preferred local atomic alignment:        0
Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:   64
Error correction support:            0
Unified memory for Host and Device:      0
Profiling timer resolution:          1
Device endianess:                Little
Available:                   Yes
Compiler available:              Yes
Execution capabilities:              
Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
Execute native function:             No
Queue on Host properties:                
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  Yes
Queue on Device properties:              
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  No
Platform ID:                     0x7f179f671e98
Name:                        Oland
Vendor:                  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device OpenCL C version:             OpenCL C 1.2 
Driver version:              2348.3
Profile:                     FULL_PROFILE
Version:                     OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2348.3)
Extensions:                  cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_spir cl_khr_gl_event 


Device Type:                     CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
Vendor ID:                   1002h
Board name:                  
Max compute units:               8
Max work items dimensions:           3
Max work items[0]:               1024
Max work items[1]:               1024
Max work items[2]:               1024
Max work group size:                 1024
Preferred vector width char:             16
Preferred vector width short:            8
Preferred vector width int:          4
Preferred vector width long:             2
Preferred vector width float:            8
Preferred vector width double:       4
Native vector width char:            16
Native vector width short:           8
Native vector width int:             4
Native vector width long:            2
Native vector width float:           8
Native vector width double:          4
Max clock frequency:                 3852Mhz
Address bits:                    64
Max memory allocation:           4182621184
Image support:               Yes
Max number of images read arguments:         128
Max number of images write arguments:        64
Max image 2D width:              8192
Max image 2D height:                 8192
Max image 3D width:              2048
Max image 3D height:                 2048
Max image 3D depth:              2048
Max samplers within kernel:          16
Max size of kernel argument:             4096
Alignment (bits) of base address:        1024
Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:  128
Single precision floating point capability
Denorms:                     Yes
Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
Round to nearest even:           Yes
Round to zero:               Yes
Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
Cache type:                  Read/Write
Cache line size:                 64
Cache size:                  32768
Global memory size:              16730484736
Constant buffer size:                65536
Max number of constant args:             8
Local memory type:               Global
Local memory size:               32768
Max pipe arguments:              16
Max pipe active reservations:            16
Max pipe packet size:                4182621184
Max global variable size:            1879048192
Max global variable preferred total size:    1879048192
Max read/write image args:           64
Max on device events:                0
Queue on device max size:            0
Max on device queues:                0
Queue on device preferred size:      0
SVM capabilities:                
Coarse grain buffer:             No
Fine grain buffer:               No
Fine grain system:               No
Atomics:                     No
Preferred platform atomic alignment:         0
Preferred global atomic alignment:       0
Preferred local atomic alignment:        0
Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:   1
Error correction support:            0
Unified memory for Host and Device:      1
Profiling timer resolution:          1
Device endianess:                Little
Available:                   Yes
Compiler available:              Yes
Execution capabilities:              
Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
Execute native function:             Yes
Queue on Host properties:                
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  Yes
Queue on Device properties:              
Out-of-Order:                No
Profiling :                  No
Platform ID:                     0x7f179f671e98
Name:                        Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Vendor:                  GenuineIntel
Device OpenCL C version:             OpenCL C 1.2 
Driver version:              2348.3 (sse2,avx)
Profile:                     FULL_PROFILE
Version:                     OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2348.3)
Extensions:                  cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_media_ops2 cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_spir cl_khr_gl_event
```

Comment: Are you able to run other examples? Your clinfo shows `Address bits:                    32` so maybe you should try with 32 bit version.

Comment: I have the same problem with other samples. My linux is a 64bits system. Do you think i have to try to install the driver with a 32 bits version?

Comment: Well, it is bizarre that the address bits show 32 bits. I don't know the specs of that GPU, but it shouldn't be 32 bit addressed I suppose. You can try running it with CPU, if that works, maybe its a driver issue for your GPU. I'm not sure if installing 32bit version of the driver and AMD APP SDK would work or not, you can try anyway.